# Move objects between containers and lose the interface

Tags: delphi, inheritance, object, interface

Let's say we have interface `I`, object `O` and a container `sl`:

```
type
  rootInterface = Interface
  end;

  childOfRootInterface = interface(rootInterface)
  end;

  ObjectImplementsRootInterface = class(TObject, I)
  end;

  ObjectImplementsChildOfRootInterface = class(TOtherObject, I2);
  end;

var
  aStringList: TStringList;
```

Assuming that `sl` is initialized.

If we do

```
aStringList.Items.AddObject('root', ObjectImplementsRootInterface );
```

then we can't do

```
ObjectImplementsRootInterface  := I(aStringList.Items.Objects([0]));
```

because Delphi forbids this. so trying:

```
ObjectImplementsRootInterface  := TObject(aStringList.Items.Objects([0]));
```

However, we inserted an `childOfRootInterface` and we want back an `childOfRootInterface` so we do

```
ObjectImplementsChildOfRootInterface  := childOfRootInterface (sl.Items.Objects([0]));
```

But `ObjectImplementsChildOfRootInterface` and `ObjectImplementsRootInterface` have different supers!

Although they support the same interface, we can't do anything.

In java you can pass around objects, as long as they support interface, In java it would be possible, so now after all this planning; what can I do in Delphi?

Update: changed the names, however the example might got over me and won, can't find right and left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working code example:

```
program Project9054004;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, Dialogs;

type  
  I = interface
  ['{6D39CF0A-839A-4DA3-B058-52E424702652}']
  end;

  O = class(TInterfacedObject, I)
  end;

var
  SL: TStrings;
  TempO: O;
  TempI: I;
begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;

  SL := TStringlist.Create;
  try
    TempO := O.Create;
    SL.AddObject('a', TempO);

    if Supports(SL.Objects[0], I, TempI) then
    begin
      // use I
      TempI._AddRef;
      TempI._Release;
    end;

    ShowMessage(SL.Objects[0].ClassName);

  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end.
```

To avoid a hard type cast I use a GUID for the interface.

Supports can be used for a safe test and assignment of the object to a variable of type I. Note that type names are a bit confusing in your example.

Hard typecasting to an interface is not possible for items in the object list.

Comment: Seems you have many projects in your default *Projects* directory (+1 :)

Comment: It is the Stackoverflow question number ;)

Comment: That's going to leak. You are mixing object references and interface references.

Comment: you deserve the +1 for claiming that my naming convention is hell.

Comment: Updated, no memory leaks and no crash anymore

Answer (score 0):

Simply gave up, and added another data structure that can contain that XML and hopefully keep an Invariant that they must not be resorted.